# How does Ireland-Rosen reduce the coefficient of $z^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ into this neat form in Kronecker proof of Gaussian sums?

Tags: number-theory, power-series, binomial-coefficients, exponentiation, gauss-sums

Was reading Ireland-Rosen intro to number theory and ran into an expression on page 75 I couldn't make sense of.

They assert that (it is easy to see that) the coefficient of $z^\frac{p-1}{2}$ in the power series expansion of $e^{(2k-1)z}-e^{z(p-(2k-1))}$ is $4k-p-2$, which is clearly just the difference $(2k-1)-(p-(2k-1))$.

But I don't know how they got there, I expect something much more ugly and hard to work with looking like $\frac{(2k-1)^\frac{p-1}{2}-(p-(2k-1))^\frac{p-1}{2}}{(\frac{p-1}{2})!}$ which I then try to binomial expand and cancel terms but I don't see how they got to $4k-p-2$.

Picture included for fun times.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The factor $4k-p-2$ is the coefficient of $z^1$, not of $z^{(p-1)/2}$, in the factor
$$
\begin{split}
e^{(2k-1)z} - e^{(p-(2k-1))z}
&
= \bigl( 1 + (2k-1)z + O(z^2) \bigr)
- \bigl( 1 + (p-2k+1)z + O(z^2) \bigr)
\\ &
= (4k-p-2) z + O(z^2)
.
\end{split}
$$
It's only when you take the **product** that you get the coefficient of $z^{(p-1)/2}$ in the whole thing; this is because
$$
\bigl( a_1 z + O(z^2) \bigr)
\bigl( a_2 z + O(z^2) \bigr)
\cdots
\bigl( a_n z + O(z^2) \bigr)
=
a_1 a_2 \cdots a_n z^{n} + O(z^{n+1})
.
$$

Comment: I see! I ignored the product because it appeared in both expressions. I thought about that it doesn't matter for the sum, and white-noised it in the product. Silly me.